# Is a link to jsfiddle with an explanation a valid answer

Tags: discussion, answers, jsfiddle

I just came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33213152/290340).

Quality issues aside, I was considering leaving a nagging comment about answering a question with an external link is not acceptable.

However...

Despite linking to the code externally, the answer does contain a reasonable explanation of what the code does.

Should this new user be nudged a bit, or is this form of answer perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Does the answer answer the question if the link is broken? if not, it's not valid.

Answer (score 7):

No. When you try to post that without the code block you get this message:

> Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code. ...

[An answer is not an answer with just a link.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/245360) The problem with this kind of post that it will render invalid when the URL dies (no matter how reliable the source might be).

This answer must be edited (which I have done) or deleted. It is appropriate to flag it as 'not an answer'.

I disagree 'the answer does contain a reasonable explanation of what the code does'. It does not in my opinion. The only 'real content' are two half sentences that I have a hard time to understand / place in its context.

Comment: Wow... that's the first time I've seen a live code snippet in an answer. I didn't know SO had that capability.

Comment: @EvanPlaice - It's fairly new, relatively speaking. They've only had [runnable snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/tags/stackexchange/page2/) for a little over a  year.

Comment: As an aside, we aren't legally supposed to import content from JSFiddle. The licensing is different and as such doing that shouldn't be encouraged. You can leave a comment that the code should be in the answer and flag as NaA (if the author edits the code into the question the NaA flag will be voided). cc@Evan

Comment: @TinyGiant Patrick already converted the answer but thanks for the heads up anyway. I'll keep an eye out for JSFiddle links.